# How to make List of Data as pandas dataframe for looping?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i seems cant find the right answer after spending long time searching for the correct problem here

so, i got
`sites = df_sim1['site_id'].unique()`

```
['XXX092' 'XXX093']
```

i'm using it to create 2 dataframes from 1 big dataframe

```
for site in sites:
 exec(f"{site} = df_sim1[df_sim1['site_id']==site].reset_index(drop=True)")
 f"{site} = {site}.drop(['site_id'], axis=1)"
```

and got 2 dataframes XXX092, XXX093

so I need to remove the column 'site_id', i'm thinking about looping it again

```
for site in sites:
for column in site.columns:
    if "site_id" in column:
        site.drop(column, axis = 1, inplace=True)
```

i got error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'columns'"

if i'm defining the sites as

```
sites = [XXX092, XXX093]
```

i got my desired result which column 'site_id' removed from all my dataframe,
any clue where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error comes from the fact that `site` is a string, the way you define it (values in unique sites), and you are calling looking for a `columns` attribute inside of it which it does not have as it is not a dataframe.

I think what you want is:

```py
[site_df.drop(columns='site_id') for site, site_df in df_sim1.groupby('site_id')]
```

which would give a list of dataframe, partitioning the`df_sim1` into `site_id` unique values, and dropping the value of `site_id` in each.

Comment: well, thank you
i think that could works, but i think i might be a little lost in the process, how do i call for the specific dataframe? for example if i want to process only XXX093?

Comment: If you only want to do it for some sites, add a filter to the list comprehension